# Passing jQuery ajax value back to calling JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem passing data from a JQuery ajax call back to the calling location. The code in question is below:

```
jQuery("#button").click(function()
{   
    for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++)
    {
        result = updateUser(data[i]); //result is not populated..
                    alert(result); //prints 'undefined'

    }
});

function updateUser(user_id)
{       
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"/users/update/"+user_id,
        type:"GET",
        async: false,
        success: (function(data){           
            //if I alert "data" here it shows up correctly
                            //but if i try to return it like below 
                            //it does not get passed correctly 
                            return data; 
        })
    });
```

Any pointers are greatly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery ajax request inside a function: how to return the value I got?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619888/jquery-ajax-request-inside-a-function-how-to-return-the-value-i-got)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot return value from an AJAX success handler like that. AJAX is asynchronous so execution will proceed to the next line where `result` is `undefined`. The only way you can get data back from an asynchronous operation is to use a callback. A callback is a function that gets called when the asynchronous operation finishes what it is doing:

```
jQuery("#button").click(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        updateUser(data[i], function(result) {
            alert(result);
        });
    }
});

function updateUser(user_id, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/users/update/" + user_id,
        type: "GET",
        success: callback
    });
}
```

Here, you're calling the callback in the success handler of the AJAX call and so now you have access to the data that was returned by the AJAX call.

Comment: pretty dang similar to mine :P beat you to the punch by like 10 seconds

Comment: Why the downvote? If you're going to downvote at least explain why.

Comment: 1. because you've forced it to be synchronous, 2. because it doesn't use the `Deferred` pattern for handling this scenario. 3. you might as well just have said `success: callback` without the extra closure.

Comment: wasn't me -_-, but someone doesn't like my answer either and no explanation

Comment: @Alnitak I used the OP's code. I didn't notice that it was `async`. Hardly a reason to downvote. This answer is correct. Also, just because it doesn't use `Deferred` doesn't make it wrong either. You're right about just using the callback. I wrote it a little too quick.

Comment: @VivinPaliath yeah, I see now that the OP used sync too.  However `Deferred` really is the right way of doing this since jQuery 1.5 - there's _zero_ need to pass around callbacks any more.

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah the `Deferred` approach does look much nicer. Thanks for pointing me to that!

Comment: @VivinPaliath: Sorry, but I did not understand your answer. What function is the `callback`? When I called `updateUser` as the callback it put me in an infinite loop..

Comment: `updateUser` is not the callback. Look at the second argument I'm passing to `updateUser`. It's a function-literal that ends up being your callback.

Comment: @VivinPaliath: When I say `success:callback`, it gives me error saying callback is undefined :(

Comment: @open_sourse Are you sure you're passing it in?

Comment: @VivinPaliath: unless the computer is playing mindgames with me I am sure I am. Is `callback` a keyword in JS? When you say `success:callback` does it mean that the control should return to the caller function with the result of the call?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16712/discussion-between-vivin-paliath-and-open-sourse)

Comment: i just learn how we can use call back thank you @VivinPaliath

Answer (score 1):

The A in ajax is Asynchronous, which means that when the file loaded, the function that started it is done running. Try using jQuery Deferred: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Example:

```
jQuery("#button").click(function()
{   
    for(var i = 0;i < data.length; i++)
    {
        updateUser(data[i]).done(function(result) {
                    alert(result); //prints 'undefined'
        });

    }
});

function updateUser(user_id)
{
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url:"/users/update/"+user_id,
        type:"GET",
        async: false,
        success: (function(data){           
            ...
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: close, except that there's no need to create a new `Deferred` object - the `$.ajax()` function creates one for you.

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks Steve, @Alnitak How can I use the Deferred object from the jQuery.ajax() function without creating a new Deferred object?

Comment: @raphie just eliminate the `defer` variable in this answer and chnage the function so it does `return jQuery.ajax(...)`.

Comment: Thanks @Alnitak, Appreciate the input. This allowed me to use PHP session variables in Javascript, been trying to do that for couple of days with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Have your function `return` the result of calling `jQuery.ajax()` - this object implements the jQuery deferred `promise` interface.  That is, an object that promises to return a result *some time later*.

```
function updateUser(user_id) {       
    return jQuery.ajax({...});
}
```

and then use `.done()` to register the function to be called when the promise gets `resolved`:

```
updateUser(data[i]).done(function(result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

The important part is that `deferred` objects allow you to complete decouple the *initiation* of the asynchronous task (i.e. your `updateUser` function) with what's supposed to happen when that task completes (or fails).

Hence there's no need to pass any callback functions to `.ajax`, and you can also chain your call with other deferred objects (e.g. animations, other AJAX requests).

Furthermore, you can register as many `.done()` callbacks as you like, and `.fail()` callbacks too, without ever having to change `updateUser()`.

Answer (score 0):

The function that called the success function is the Ajax request and not the UpdateUser function. So obviously when you return it it will return back from the success callback but not to the UpdateUser function..

Also since the ajax is Asynchronous , buy the time the callback is executed it will come out of the UpdateUser function.. !

Answer (score -2):

pretty sure what is happening (not an expert) but you are returning 'data' for your annonomys function in success and not your whole updateUser function

```
function updateUser(user_id)
{       
    var retData;
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:"/users/update/"+user_id,
        type:"GET",
        async: false,
        success: (function(data){           
            //if I alert "data" here it shows up correctly
                            //but if i try to return it like below 
                            //it does not get passed correctly 
                            retData = data; 
        })
    return retData;
});
```

But like i said, i am no expert.