# How to return a value from a function that calls $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value, getjson

```
function lookupRemote(searchTerm)
{
   var defaultReturnValue = 1010;
   var returnValue = defaultReturnValue;

   $.getJSON(remote, function(data)
   {
      if (data != null)
      {
           $.each(data.items, function(i, item)
           {
               returnValue = item.libraryOfCongressNumber;
           });
      }
    });
    return returnValue;
}
```

Why is the `returnValue` from this function alway equal to the default value set at the beginning of the function and never to the value retrieved from the JSON lookup?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537434/cant-get-correct-return-value-from-an-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This happens because that callback function (`function(data) {...}`) runs *later* when the response comes back...because it's an asynchronous function.  Instead use the value once you have it set, like this:

```
function lookupRemote(searchTerm)
{
    var defaultReturnValue = 1010;
    var returnValue = defaultReturnValue;
    $.getJSON(remote, function(data) {           
        if (data != null) {
              $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {                 
                    returnValue = item.libraryOfCongressNumber;
              });
        }
        OtherFunctionThatUsesTheValue(returnValue);
     });
}
```

This is the way all asynchronous behavior should be, kick off whatever needs the value once you have it...which is when the server responds with data.

Answer (score 18):

If you don't want to use asynchronous function, better use the following:

```
function getValue(){
   var value= $.ajax({ 
      url: 'http://www.abc.com', 
      async: false
   }).responseText;
   return value;
}
```

This function waits until the value is returned from the server.

Comment: +1 This works like charm if you need synchronous behaviour out of. It will return JSON into String if don't want to change it to string just do `JSON.parse(value)`

Answer (score 4):

The function you pass to `getJSON` is run **when the response to the HTTP request arrives** which is **not** immediately.

The return statement executes **before** the response, so the variable hasn't yet been set.

Have your callback function do what needs doing with the data. Don't try to return it.

Answer (score 1):

```
const getJson = (path) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    $.getJSON(path, function (data) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(data);
      }, 1);
    });
  })
}
var result = await getJson('test.json');
console.log(result);
```