# return value from getJSON function

Tags: javascript, jquery, getjson

I have a function with jquery getJSON and i need the return the result value back (to Use it somewhere else)

Here is the code:

```
function getval(){
jQuery.getJSON('http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker?callback=?', function(data) {
    // We can't use .return because return is a JavaScript keyword.
    return data['return'].avg.value;
});
}

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert (getval());
    });

});
```

This is doesn't work :(

**i know i can call external function from inside the getJSON function with the value like:**

```
    jQuery.getJSON('http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker?callback=?', function(data) {
        // We can't use return because return is a JavaScript keyword.
       mysecondfunction(data['return'].avg.value);
    });
function mysecondfunction(value){
//use the value
}
```

But i have to call the **json** function from **another** function because json return a dynamic value and i need to use it.

I hope it clear...

**Thank you very much!!**

Comment: ajax is asynchronous, anything that needs the result needs to be ran in a callback that gets called after the ajax call completes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return a value from a function that calls $.getJSON?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200641/how-to-return-a-value-from-a-function-that-calls-getjson)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the final solution:

```
function getval( callback ){
    jQuery.getJSON('http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker', function(data) {
        // We can't use .return because return is a JavaScript keyword.
        callback(data['return'].avg.value);
    });
}

$(function () {
        $(document).ready(function() {
        getval( function ( value ) { 
            alert( 'Do something with ' + value + ' here!' );
        } );
    });

});
```

Thanks everyone for your help!!

Answer (score 3):

You might try using a `callback` function:

```
function getval( callback ){
    jQuery.getJSON('http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker?callback=?', function(data) {
        // We can't use .return because return is a JavaScript keyword.
        callback(data['return'].avg.value);
    });
}

$(function () {
        $(document).ready(function() {
        getval( function ( value ) { alert( 'Do something with ' + value + ' here!' ) } );
    });

});
```

Comment: Hi! just a small question.. when i use: "alert (getval( function ( value ) { alert( 'Do something here!' ) } ));" i get "undefined" can you see why?? Thank you very much!

Comment: @EranLevi - I think Kevin didn't mean for that first "alert" to be there. The line should be more like this: `getVal(function(value) { alert('value is: ' + value); }`.

Comment: Thank you! you probably meant to write: getVal(function(value) { alert('value is: ' + value); }); but the page is blank now :( can you see anything else?? Thanks man!

Comment: @KevinBoucher - Hello and thank you!! i still can't see what is wrong in this simple code: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/kf6qb/1/) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Ajax calls are asynchronous, so you can't have the `getVal()` function return something. Whatever you need to do with the result, you have to do it in inside the callback function.

```
function getval() {
    jQuery.getJSON('http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/ticker?callback=?', function(data) {
        // You have to use "data" here
        alert(data['return'].avg.value);
    });
}

$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        getval();
    });
});
```

Comment: You right, but what if i need to refresh (get) the json call again and again? (json array values changing dynamically!) thank you!

Comment: @EranLevi Then send the request again.

Comment: first.. Thanks! now, i can't send the request beause im calling from function No.1 to Function No.2, now here i cant call Function No.1 again (because it will call Func.No.2... :)... ) i really need to use the return value somehow in function No.2..

Comment: @EranLevi - You will have to move some of the code from the the one function to the other so it is inside the ajax callback function. I'd have to see the functions to comment further.

Answer (score 1):

Hi getJSON asynchronous call so its return **undefind**

so you need to fire ajax call pass with this args **asnyc:false**

Ex:

```
    function getCountrycodeJson(obj) {
     var code="";
        $.ajax({
         async: false,
          dataType : 'json',
         url: "url",
         type : 'GET',
         success: function(data) {
         for(var i in data){ 
//here do your logic and assign value for code varable   

          }
           }
      }});

        return code;
    }
```

this is working for me.....