# Still Having Problems Returning Value Through Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

I'm having serious problems with the function below:

```
    function requestUploadedSearch()
    {
        var cookie = JSON.parse(readCookie("user_search_cookie"));
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "script",
            async: false,
            data: {
                context: "search-get",
                code: removeNull(cookie, cookie !== null, "code")
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                var keywords = search_return["keywords"];
                return keywords; // here is the damn problem.
            }
        });
    }
```

Seams that simply nothing comes out of the function except for the **undefined** value and no errors are shown in the debugger.
And I'm seriously almost throwing my laptop on the wall.
If anyone could help me doing this, please answer!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problems, serious or otherwise, are you having? Have you used the  JavaScript console to identify the problems, are there any errors reported?

Comment: What is this code try to accomplish. What is NOT working for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get correct return value from an jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537434/cant-get-correct-return-value-from-an-jquery-ajax-call). The duplicate is about asynchronous calls, but the fundamental problem is the same: you're returning from the anonymous function, not from the main function.

Comment: We need to know what problem you are having. For instance, in your `success` function, I see you are using the value `search_return`, but you pass `data` into the function and don't use it.

Comment: Well, sorry for that, I promise I will edit it. The problem is: Nothing comes out of that damn function and nothing is reported! A **undefined** just appears at the end.

Comment: @user1055350 - it is undefined because of the closure issue -- see my answer

Answer (score 2):

1st off: Where is the `search_return` variable? Why are you ignoring `data`?

I have a feeling this is what you want to do:

```
function requestUploadedSearch()
{
    var cookie = JSON.parse(readCookie("user_search_cookie"));
    var keywords;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        data: {
            context: "search-get",
            code: removeNull(cookie, cookie !== null, "code")
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            keywords = data["keywords"];
        }
    });
    return keywords;
}
```

Comment: Exactly! But how do I write the JSON in the server-side aplication?

Comment: @Hogan: Slightly different. You're using `dataType: 'script'`, I'm using `dataType: 'json'` which drastically changes how the data being passed into the callback is interpreted.

Comment: @user1055350: That's a completely separate issue, and should probably be posted as another question.

Comment: I guess you could say it is different, however the OP clearly did not understand closures, which was main issue and at least explained in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the scope you're trying to return your keywords from. The success function is called by jQuery, and you don't have any control over what jQuery does with that return value. You could do `return $.ajax(...` but you wouldn't get what you expect, since according to the documentation: "As of jQuery 1.5, the $.ajax() method returns the jqXHR object, which is a superset of the XMLHTTPRequest object" (http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jqXHR).

What you should do instead is set up a callback function like:

```
function doSomethingWithKeywords(keywords) {
    // do stuff
};
```

and in the success function call that function:

```
doSomethingWithKeywords(keywords);
```

**EDIT:** Hogan's is a good solution, since your call isn't asynchronous.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that since the Ajax call will complete at an arbitrary time in the future, you cannot simply return a value from its `success` handler.

One issue is that you're not actually doing anything with the `data` returned by the server, which seems puzzling.

The nutshell version is that you need to implement the functionality as part of the `success` callback. That can be done in-line, or you can create the callback function outside of the Ajax call itself and use it as the value for the `success` property:

```
function onSuccess(data) {
    // Do something with the data here
}

...

$.ajax({ // etc.
    success: onSuccess
};
```

You may also use [jQuery's $.when function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Comment: He has set `async: true` though.

Comment: @flesk I think you mean `false`. But that doesn't mean returning a value from the `success` handler returns a value from the enclosing function. I'm also guessing the OP did that in attempt to do what he thought he was doing, rather than because it needs to be, or should be, synchronous.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. :$ I agree with you on that, as I also posted in my answer. And yeah, that's probably the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is the return you are passing is not the return of the function -- it is the return of the event of success.  Often closures (implied passing of a local variable to a function) are used to solve this problem in JavaScript.

**NB**  I still don't think your function will work because I don't see where `search_return["keywords"]` is defined.  But at least you won't have to worry about the closure issue.  Once your success function is correct the main function will return it.

Like this:

```
function requestUploadedSearch()
{
    var cookie = JSON.parse(readCookie("user_search_cookie"));
    var returnClosure;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "script",
        async: false,
        data: {
            context: "search-get",
            code: removeNull(cookie, cookie !== null, "code")
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            // returnClosure = data["keywords"];
            returnClosure = search_return["keywords"];
        }
    });
    return returnClosure;
}
```

Comment: `search_return["keywords"]` looks like it should be `data["keywords"]`