# Returning a value from a jQuery Ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use Javascript in an OO style, and one method needs to make a remote call to get some data so a webpage can work with it.  I've created a Javascript class to encapsulate the data retrieval so I can re-use the logic elsewhere, like so:

```
 AddressRetriever = function() { 
   AddressRetriever.prototype.find = function(zip) { 
       var addressList = [];
       $.ajax({ 
           /* setup stuff */
           success: function(response) { 
               var data = $.parseJSON(response.value);
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                   var city = data[i].City; // "City" column of DataTable
                   var state = data[i].State; // "State" column of DataTable
                   var address = new PostalAddress(postalCode, city, state); // This is a custom JavaScript class with simple getters, a DTO basically.
                   addressList.push(address);
               }
           }
       });
       return addressList;
   }
 }
```

The webpage itself calls this like follows:

```
$('#txtZip').blur(function() { 
    var retriever = new AddressRetriever();
    var addresses = retriever.find($(this).val());

    if (addresses.length > 0) { 
        $('#txtCity').val(addresses[0].getCity());
        $('#txtState').val(addresses[0].getState());
    }
});
```

The problem is that sometimes `addresses` is inexplicably empty (i.e. length = 0).  In Firebug the XHR tab shows a response coming back with the expected data, and if I set an alert inside of the success method the length is correct, but outside of that method when I try to return the value, it's sometimes (but not always) empty and my textbox doesn't get populated.  Sometimes it shows up as empty but the textbox gets populated properly anyways.

I know I could do this by getting rid of the separate class and stuffing the whole ajax call into the event handler, but I'm looking for a way to do this correctly so the function can be reused if necessary.  Any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get correct return value from an jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537434/cant-get-correct-return-value-from-an-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: It sounds like you need to include an "error:" handler and return addressList within the success block. Also, since it is async. call, the "return addressList" can be occurring before the ajax call is complete.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript asynchronous return value / assignment with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7779697/javascript-asynchronous-return-value-assignment-with-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, you can't do it the way you're trying to do it with asynchronous ajax calls.

Ajax methods usually run asynchronous.  Therefore, when the ajax function call itself returns (where you have `return addressList` in your code), the actual ajax networking has not yet completed and the results are not yet known.

Instead, you need to rework how the flow of your code works and deal with the results of the ajax call ONLY in the success handler or in functions you call from the success handler. Only when the success handler is called has the ajax networking completed and provided a result.

In a nutshell, you can't do normal procedural programming when using asynchronous ajax calls.  You have to change the way your code is structured and flows.  It does complicate things, but the user experience benefits to using asynchronous ajax calls are huge (the browser doesn't lock up during a networking operation).

Here's how you could restructure your code while still keeping the `AddressRetriever.find()` method fairly generic using a callback function:

```
AddressRetriever = function() { 
   AddressRetriever.prototype.find = function(zip, callback) { 
       $.ajax({ 
           /* setup stuff */
           success: function(response) { 
               var addressList = [];
               var data = $.parseJSON(response.value);
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                   var city = data[i].City; // "City" column of DataTable
                   var state = data[i].State; // "State" column of DataTable
                   var address = new PostalAddress(postalCode, city, state); // This is a custom JavaScript class with simple getters, a DTO basically.
                   addressList.push(address);
               }
               callback(addressList);
           }
       });
   }
 }

$('#txtZip').blur(function() { 
    var retriever = new AddressRetriever();
    retriever.find($(this).val(), function(addresses) {
        if (addresses.length > 0) { 
            $('#txtCity').val(addresses[0].getCity());
            $('#txtState').val(addresses[0].getState());
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Okay so it looks like I need to include the callback, and then I can keep my code structured properly while still being able to use the Ajax methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
    AddressRetriever = function() { 
   AddressRetriever.prototype.find = function(zip) { 
       var addressList = [];
       $.ajax({ 
           /* setup stuff */
           success: function(response) { 
               var data = $.parseJSON(response.value);
               for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
                   var city = data[i].City; // "City" column of DataTable
                   var state = data[i].State; // "State" column of DataTable
                   var address = new PostalAddress(postalCode, city, state); // This is a custom JavaScript class with simple getters, a DTO basically.
                   addressList.push(address);
                   processAddresss(addressList);
               }
           }
       });
   }
 }

function processAddresss(addressList){
     if (addresses.length > 0) { 
        $('#txtCity').val(addresses[0].getCity());
        $('#txtState').val(addresses[0].getState());
    }
}
```

or if you want don't want to make another function call, make the ajax call synchronous. Right now, it is returning the array before the data is pushed into the array

Comment: This implementation makes the `.find()` hard-wired to one specific web page and one specific object on that page.  That drastically reduces the usefulness of the AddressRetriever object.  Using a callback function lets the data object stay independent of the HTML and lets the data be used for lots of different things and lots of different page designs, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Not inexplicable at all, the list won't be filled until an indeterminate amount of time in the future.

The canonical approach is to do the work in your success handler, perhaps by passing in your own callback. You may also use [jQuery's `.when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Answer (score 0):

AJAX calls are asynchroneous, which means they don't run with the regular flow of the program. When you execute

```
if (addresses.length > 0) {
```

`addresses` is in fact, empty, as the program did not wait for the AJAX call to complete.