# Global variable not set value in $.getJSON properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have declared global variable named counter=0 on my index.html page inside head section

```
<script>
var counter=0;
</script>
```

now in my one of function i am setting its value as

```
    function getCounter(param)
    {
        $.getJSON("somewebserviceURL&format=json&callback=?",
            function(data)
            {
                 $.each(data, function(i, item)
                    {
                        counter++;
                    });

            });
//I am not able to get the latest value here & in upcoming functions which use this variable
         alert(counter);

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't get correct return value from an jQuery Ajax call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537434/cant-get-correct-return-value-from-an-jquery-ajax-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `getJSON` is asynchronous. This means the `counter` variable will not have been incremented before `alert(counter)` is hit. Instead, move the alert to just after your `$.each()` loop:

```
function getCounter(param) {
    $.getJSON(
        "somewebserviceURL&format=json&callback=?",
        function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                counter++;
            });
            alert(counter);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: can you tell me the way that i can get count value outside of $.getJSON() call or if i use $.POST() method from jquery does it resolve problem?

Comment: You can only work with the count value inside the callback function of an AJAX method, whether you do this directly, as in your example, or by calling a function elsewhere and passing your variables to it.

Comment: basically i want $.getJSON() should executed its success function & code should run according to line numbers means top to bottom without skipping any line

Answer (score 1):

Simply because your `alert()` is processed faster than your `counter++;`

Your `.getJSON()` is simply an AJAX-Call which is asynchronous.

- http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/

Which means the JavaScript code, does not wait until your AJAX Call is finished, it continues without waiting.

Answer (score 1):

That is because getJSON is sent asynchronously. Your alert is called before the success-callback of getJSON. The success-callback isn't called until you have the response, by then alert() has already fired.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getCounter(param)
{
    $.getJSON("somewebserviceURL&format=json&callback=?",
        function(data)
        {
             $.each(data, function(i, item)
                {
                    counter++;
                });
             // try this
             alert(counter);
        }
     );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use a callback for this :

```
function getCounter(param, callback) {
    $.getJSON("somewebserviceURL&format=json&callback=?",
        function(data)
        {
             $.each(data, function(i, item)
                {
                    counter++;
                });

             callback.call(this, counter);
        }
     );
}

getCounter(param, function(counter) { alert(counter);  } );
```

Answer (score 0):

All of are true here that GetJson is asynchronous!

Just shift alert() to inside fore each loop to see affected value as per below

```
 function getCounter(param)
    {
        $.getJSON("somewebserviceURL&format=json&callback=?",
            function(data)
            {
                 $.each(data, function(i, item)
                    {
                        counter++;
                        alert(counter);

                    });

            });

    }
```