# How to return json from $.getJSON (coffeescript)

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can’t get correct return value from an jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537434/cant-get-correct-return-value-from-an-jquery-ajax-call)
>   [How to return the response from an AJAX call from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call-from-a-function)

I have this:

```
  get_json = (url) ->
    $.getJSON "#{url}.json", {}, (json, response) ->
      return json
```

But this compiles to:

```
getJson = function(url) {
  return $.getJSON("" + url + ".json", {}, function(json, response) {
    return json;
  });
};
```

..and returns the response object. How can I return just the json instead?

Comment: Unlike mentioned questions, this one asks for trouble with coffescript -> js conversion

Comment: Is that a joke? The issue is with coffeescript 'returning' $.getJSON. Those other questions do not answer this.

Comment: Removed jquery tag so people don't get confused. The trouble is that coffeescript is returning the response object by default and I don't know how to prevent that.

Comment: The problem is exactly the same. AJAX is asynchronous. By the time the server has given the JSON, script execution is already way past that line.

Comment: @Zenph I'm restoring the jQuery tag, as this question is definitely about using jQuery's `$.getJSON` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A deferred object is being returned, use it to get your data. With your current implementation of the `get_json` method, this JavaScript should work:

```
get_json("http://example.com").done(function(obj){
    console.log(obj);
});
```

your code can be simplified to:

```
get_json = (url) ->
    $.getJSON "#{url}.json"
```

There is nothing wrong with the conversion, what's wrong is your assumption of how ajax requests work.

You can't have a function that has a url parameter that sends off an ajax request and returns the data from the function without making the ajax request synchronous (which is a bad idea for various reasons).

Comment: Got it thanks. Got some studying to do :)

Comment: I guess in a way coffee script did the right thing by returning the response,  :-p