# Call the same $http.get() in 2 different directives using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am using AngularJS and D3.JS

I have an html form with the following:

```
    <div simple-chart chart-data="lineData"></div>
```

This is hooked up to a directive like so:

```
mist.directive("simpleChart", function($window, $http){
    return{
        restrict: "EA",
        template: "<svg width='750' height='200'></svg>",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            function drawLineChart() {
                //initilize the line chart
            }
            $http.get("myurl")
            .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
                drawLineChart();
            })
        }}
  });
```

1. Is it possible to create another directive using the data from $http.get("myurl") without having to call it again?
2. Is is possible to make $http.get("myurl") common so that it can be called by different directives?
3. Can I use something like this? [Can't get correct return value from an jQuery Ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537434/cant-get-correct-return-value-from-an-jquery-ajax-call)

Comment: Use service/factory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a service which returns $http.get('myurl') and add it as a dependency in your directive.

```
mist.factory('dataService', function ($http) {
    var dataService= {};
    dataService.getData = function(){
       return $http.get('myurl');
    }
    return dataService;

});

mist.directive("simpleChart", function($window, dataService){
return{
    restrict: "EA",
    template: "<svg width='750' height='200'></svg>",
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        function drawLineChart() {
            //initilize the line chart
        }
        dataService.getData()
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            drawLineChart();
        })
    }}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your http calls into a service and use something like [angular-cache](https://github.com/jmdobry/angular-cache) to cache the response from the server.

Comment: Since I'm a beginner, I found angular-cache too advanced for me but I did read up on $cacheFactory.Cache and that seemed to be something that I might be able to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using AngularJS1.3, I needed to use

```
            mist.factory('dataService', function ($http) {
            return {
                getData: function () {
                    //since $http.get returns a promise,
                    //and promise.then() also returns a promise
                    //that resolves to whatever value is returned in it's
                    //callback argument, we can return that.
                    return $http.get('http://url.com').then(function (result) {
                        return result.data;
                    });
                }
            };
        });

        mist.directive("simpleChart", function ($window, dataService) {
            return{
                restrict: "EA",
                template: "<svg width='750' height='200'></svg>",
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    function drawLineChart() {
                        //initilize the line chart
                    }
                    dataService.getData().then(
                            function (data) {
                                drawLineChart();
                            },
                            function (err) {
                                console.log("Sorry we encountered an error " + err);
                            }
                    );
                }};
        });
```

SOURCE: http://www.benlesh.com/2013/02/angularjs-creating-service-with-http.html